# Remove border lines appearing between paragraphs formatted with the same style

Tags: microsoft-word

I defined a custom paragraph-level style in Word 365 that, relative to the normal Style, indents the text right, applies some text level formatting, and separates the text using horizontal border lines.

In paragraphs governed by this style, I often make use of further indentation to separate out lists etc. However, additional border lines are (annoyingly) created among those differently indented paragraphs.

Additionally, when returning the indent in the next paragraph, it goes back further left. All is shown in the screenshots below.

[image]
[image]

I've played around with all the options under the style's paragraph and border settings, but none changes this behaviour. Are there any other options I could use in order to get rid of these additional border lines?

Answer (score 3):

As you correctly figured out, the border settings are influenced by the indentation of a paragraph (since the border width is based on the paragraph width, which depends on the indentation).

So, you basically have 3 options now to achieve your goal:

1. You could create a "top" style which only has a top border and a "bottom" style which only has a bottom border. Apply these styles to the first and last paragraph of your section that you want to enclose into your borders.
2. You could keep a single style and within that style simply define tabs. See, tabs do not influence the paragraph width and therefore also not the border settings. Note however, that you will need to manually press the tab key on each line that you want to indent as opposed to only the first line of a paragraph. When tabbing the second line or a following one, you might have to hold down the CTRL key while pressing tab or otherwise Word might again indent your paragraph instead of moving it to the next tab.

[image]

3. If you only want to indent a **single line**, then you can of course also make use of the single-line indent which will not influence the whole paragraph width and thus it won't lead to additional borders.

[image]