Create cross-page border in Word
I am trying to find some way to create borders that can run across a page break in Microsoft Word.  The closest I have come to this objective is to create a table with a single cell.  However there does not appear to be a way to prevent the cell from putting a bottom and top border on either side of a page break.
Here is a screenshot of what happens, with the borders that I don't want to appear scribbled out in blue:

Is there a way to prevent the borders marked out in blue from appearing?
Or are there other approaches for getting this "special block" effect in a way that spans multiple pages?  (Note that I have considered shading but I do not want to do that because it does not reproduce well on hardcopies.)

This needs to be done in three operations.

on the top paragraph set the top border
on the bottom paragraph, set the bottom border
select the text between the top and bottom borders and set the left and right borders.

Reason if you select all the text and set the top border, you will get the top border on the first paragraph at the top of every page.  If you set the bottom, you will get the bottom border at the bottom of every page.
EDIT
An alternative method if there are indents.

Create a one cell table and paste the text in it.
Remove the top and bottom borders
Go one paragraph above the section to be enclosed and set a bottom border
Go one paragraph below the section and set a top border


This seems promising, but I can't quite get this to work: Outside of a table cell, if any of the contents are indented then the border on that block indents also.  And if you mean to apply it to the paragraph inside the table cell, then there is a small gap between paragraph top border and the cell's side borders.  Is there a way to eliminate that gap?

Are you doing this in a table or is it just a bunch of paragraphs that you need a border?

It's for blocks of things that can include paragraphs, tables, images, lists.  Putting the block inside a table cell was just one of my attempts to accomplish the goal.

I know this isn't a solution but in my answer to a question from a few weeks ago, you will see why the paragraph border option doesn't work in your case:
https://superuser.com/a/1834499/1819760
I honestly don't think that there is an easy way around this. The only workaround I can think of is:

Insert a table with 1 column and 2 rows
Put all the content that should be on the first page into the first row and all the content that should be on the second page in the second row.You will have to distribute the content well enough, so that the first row really stays on the first page and the second row stays on the second page.
Click into the first row, go to the table design tab and there deactivate the bottom border. The bottom border of the first row is basically the border in between the two rows. Like that, this border will disappear.

Please keep in mind, that this workaround is very manual! As soon as you add text before the table, you will have to re-distribute the content within the table, as the table will be shifted down.


Use a paragraph border
Preferably, this would be done in a paragraph style if you are going to do it more than once.
You need the More Borders and Shading... dialog to do this.

This only works if none of the paragraph blocks are indented.  In the example in my post the border is broken inwards by both the table and the numbered list.
